# How to fix Visual Studio "AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'getproperty'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, text-to-speech, pyttsx

This is my code:

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
print(voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty('voice',voices[0].id)




def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

if __name__=="__main__":
    speak("hello world")
```

Note: I have already installed the pyttsx3 module

ERROR:

```
[Running] python -u "f:\jarvis\jarvis.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\jarvis\jarvis.py", line 3, in <module>
    voices = engine.getproperty('voices')
AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'getproperty'

[Done] exited with code=1 in 2.08 seconds
```

Help me please
How to fix this?

Comment: Did you mean `voices = engine.getProperty('voices')`? The code you posted works fine for me, but your full error traceback (well done for posting it) reveals some different code that *you* are actually running. Try copying your own code out of your question and run that.

Comment: I copied this code out of my code and pasted it in this question.               I double checked every step but still this error is coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python identifiers are case sensitive.

You wrote:

> ```
> voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
> ```

which is fine, and matches [the docs](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html) exactly.

The diagnostic you show is for some different code:

> ```
> voices = engine.getproperty('voices')
> AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'getproperty'
> ```

The diagnostic is correct.
While there *is* a `getProperty` attribute,
the engine lacks `getproperty`.
Those are two different identifiers.
Spell it correctly and your program will work better.

Comment: I spelled it exactly as in this question but still this error is coming. I even double checked it. I spelled it `getProperty` but still , the error is showing as`'Engine' object has no attribute 'getproperty'`

Comment: If you are seeing this error then you **must** have the wrong spelling somewhere.

Comment: I am getting the exact same error. <br> File "c:\Users\SIDDHESH\Projects\file_reader.py", line 11, in speak
    engine.runandwait()
AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'runandwait'